Light is Dim after Bypassing receiver on Ceiling fan
I am trying to bypass the remote control receiver in a ceiling fan. This light is LED; it’s also dimmable and changes colors with the remote. From the receiver I have two sets of wiring harnesses; one controls the light and the other controls the fan. I am certain the harness with the three wires of blue, white, and yellow control the light. Connecting the white to the common white and either red, yellow or both to the power supply does turn the light on but in its dimmest setting. Would a dimmer switch solve this? Any other ideas?
This fan was purchased from Amazon. It is a Sofucor fan, model #5247-WH-DC-YM.
This ceiling box is wired for both a fan and light to work independently. I have wired one switch to the receiver and then to the fan. Now the fan works with the remote and changes speed correctly.
The other switch I wired to the light bypassing the receiver. When this switch is flipped the light operates but it is always at the dimmest setting. I’d like to figure out how to make the light brighter (not with the remote because I’ve bypassed the receiver but just at a brighter setting whenever the switch is flipped).

First of all, the "transmitter" is the remote control - it transmits radio signals to the "receiver" which is the box with two sets of wiring harnesses that receives the signals and does stuff with them. Depending on what else the receiver does and how the light actually works, separate power wires and switches for the fan vs. light might allow you to use an ordinary dimmer, but very well might now. To help figure this out: Model # of fan and pictures of the wiring harnesses.

Thanks for the correction. I cannot understand how to add a photo I took but the harness is pretty basic; it simply connects these three wires from the receiver to the fixture. I added model and manufacturer of the fan to the posting.

It appears to be available under multiple brands including as this item at Home Depot: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Keazile-Belenus-52-in-indoor-Matte-White-Ceiling-Fan-with-Remote-Control-and-Reversible-Motor-KZ-5247-WH-DC-YM-60/331683233 which includes a manual that is typical Chinglish and not all that helpful. But it looks pretty clear that the dim/color change functions are all handled in the receiver so I highly doubt you'll be able to bypass and make it work with a regular dimmer. The way you could try but at risk of zapping the lights is to disconnect the light (blue/white wires)

and wire it up carefully directly to a dimmer switch and see whether it works or not. Which means a good bit of not-to-code jury-rigging. Be careful.

Note that one classic reason for lights being dimmer than expected is that you have wired things in series rather than in parallel.

Responding to the recent comments:I don’t think there is anything here to wire in series.
